# Unable to use Case statement in Mysql select query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here is my query and Grouping by Transaction type C for Credit and D for Debit and

```
SELECT 
case 
WHEN ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE='C' THEN SUM(ACT.AMOUNT) END AS CreditBalance,
case 
WHEN ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE='D' THEN SUM(ACT.AMOUNT) END AS DebitBalance
FROM accounttransaction ACT 
WHERE ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE;
```

Below is my result

```
CreditBalance DebitBalance
16536          NULL
NULL           9673
```

Now I want to Subtract the balance of the A/C then I need to show as Current Balance
Account transaction table includes Accountnumber,transactiontype and amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want the grand total of all the credit / debit amounts?

If so maybe the following:-

```
SELECT Accountnumber, SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount ELSE -1 * amount END) 
FROM accounttransaction
WHERE transactiontype IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Accountnumber
```

Or to give the credit and debit amounts separately as well as the overall total

```
SELECT Accountnumber, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS CreditTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS DebitTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN -1 * amount ELSE 0 END) AS OverallTotal
FROM accounttransaction
WHERE transactiontype IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Accountnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `TransactionType`, so the results show up on different rows.  You need to remove the `group by` and move the condition expressions *inside* the `sum()`:

```
select sum(case when  ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'C' then act.amount end) as CreditBalance,
       sum(case when  ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'D' then act.amount end) as DebitBalance
from AccountTransaction act
WHERE act.TRANSACTIONTYPE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, When I remove group by I am getting the total amount Credit+Debit under CreditBalance as 26209 and under DebitBalance it is showing as NULL